# What is the difference between `xterm -e $COMMAND` and `$COMMAND` within `xterm`?

Tags: xterm

I'm surprised that there are differences between running a `$COMMAND` *in* `xterm` and running `xterm -e $COMMAND`.

As an example: if I run `tmux` as a program within `xterm`, I get different behavior than when I invoke `tmux` in a running `xterm` instance. Specifically, `vim` gets different colors (invoking within a running `xterm`'s `tmux` behaves according to my vim+tmux+xterm configuration, while running in a `xterm -e tmux` gives unconfigured colors).

I'm not trying to fix the `tmux` thing specifically - that's not why I'm here. I want to know exactly when I'll have problems between running a command in `xterm` and running a command via `xterm -e $COMMAND` so I can evaluate for myself whether or not I care to use `xterm` as the graphical front-end for shortcuts to terminal applications at all.

What is the difference between `xterm -e $COMMAND` and `xterm` --> `$COMMAND`?

Comment: Try the "-ls" option of xterm?

Comment: Huh, I forgot to mention that I'd tried that... It still resulted in a difference between `-e` and nested.

Comment: The difference is clearly in the runtime environment. I would have expected -ls to make a difference. How about e.g. `xterm -e bash -lc $COMMAND` ?

Comment: No dice for `xterm -e bash -lc $COMMAND` (where `$COMMAND` is `tmux` as described above and the difference is observed in vim's coloration; I haven't seen differences elsewhere yet...). There is still a difference in behavior between it and `xterm` --> `$COMMAND`. I also tried using my login shell `zsh` in place of `bash`. I'm starting to lean toward this only being answerable by diving into `xterm`'s source, which doesn't seem worth it...

Answer (score 0):

When you run **`xterm -e $COMMAND`**, it doesn't run your *shell* (which is doing the initialization).  It just runs *`$COMMAND`* (without running the *shell*).

The [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#OPTIONS:-e) says

```
   -e program [ arguments ... ]
           This option specifies the program (and its command line
           arguments) to be run in the xterm window.
```

and [later](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h2-ENVIRONMENT)

```
   XTERM_SHELL
        is set to the pathname of the program which is invoked.  Usually
        that is a shell program, e.g., /bin/sh.  Since it is not
        necessarily a shell program however, it is distinct from "SHELL".
```